# JavaScript Templating Engine

Tags: javascript

I would like to create **universal** templating engine in JavaScript, how to?

**HTML template**

```
<h1><%title1%></h1>
<h2><%title2%></h2>
```

**JSON file**

```
{
  "title1" : "Hello World!",
  "title2" : "Hi World!"
}
```

**Javascript**

- Find in HTML file <%title1%>
- Find in JSON file variable "title1"
- Replace <%title1%> with value of variable "title1"

Same for <%title2%>

Thanks!

Comment: At the very least, the use case you describe would require a horrible implementation.  Simply put, this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://wiki.github.com/nje/jquery/jquery-templates-proposal). It discusses a proposal (by microsoft) how support for templates could be added to the jQuery library.

In the same article you will also find an overview of some already existing template solutions (maybe you'll find something that matches your needs, instead of re-inventing the wheel).

**Update (2012-07-23):**

The jQuery templates project was abandoned more than a year ago. It seems that [Boris Moore](http://www.borismoore.com/) continues his work with the new projects [jsrender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) and [jsviews](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews).

Answer (score 0):

John Resig [Micro-Templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) is cool solution

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at my jQuery templating plugin [jQote2](http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote2/). As far as usability and speed is concerned, I have yet to see a better templating solution (trust me, I've tried them all).

It has a built in closure compiler that let's you precompile your templates (handy if you want to keep your templates in .js files) and a caching mechanism. The current version also comes with a couple of convenient methods that ease the pain of appending/prepending/replacing DOM nodes.

Give it a try, you won't regret it.
Regards